# high resolution timer in C++

Tags: c++, unix

I am reading about high resolution timer to check time taken by given function. I found following code

```
double apHiResElapsedTime::sec () const
{
  struct timeval t;
  gettimeofday (&t, 0);

  double now = 1.e-6 * t.tv_usec + t.tv_sec;

  return (now - starting_);
}
```

My question what does value 1.e-6 means here?
and Why author is doing 1.e-6 * t.tv_usec + t.tv_sec.

Request your help here.

Thanks for yout time and help.

Comment: 1.e-6 is scientific notation. The end user is converting t.tv_usecs to seconds.

Comment: 1.e-6 means 1.0 X 10^-6 or 0.000001

Answer (score 6):

`1.e-6` is a number in a [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) that is equal to `10 ^ -6`, or  `0.000001`, and is of type `double`. You can read it as «ten to the minus six».

Since `gettimeofday()` is returning time as two separate integer numbers - seconds and microseconds, microsecond portion is converted to a double value representing seconds through dividing integer microseconds value by a million. Then, whole seconds (`tv_sec`) are added to the result.

For example, let's say `gettimeofday()` returns 6 seconds and 5 microseconds, this code would do `5 * 0.000001 + 6` and yield 6.000005 seconds.

On a side note, `gettimeofday()` is not really considered a high-resolution clock (and certainly has nothing to do with timers), and it is also deprecated. You should consider using [`clock_gettime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html) instead. It supports various types of «clocks» and is capable of nanosecond precision. For performance measurements, people tend to use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` flag to access wall clock that is not NTP adjusted. Note that it might not be available on all systems. On OS X, for example, `mach_absolute_time()` must be used instead.

I would also recommend to avoid using FPU (float, double types). Just stick with two integers instead. For example, if you are using `clock_gettime()`, you can calculate a difference without doubles. Here is a very simple example for you in C99 (I am sure you can convert this to C++ easily):

```
//
// C99 program that demonstrates the usage of `clock_gettime()`
// and shows how to calculate a difference between two timestamps
// in nanoseconds.
//
// $ gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 ./test.c -o ./test -lrt
//

#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int64_t
get_elapsed_time(const struct timespec * restrict start_time,
                 const struct timespec * restrict end_time)
{
    int64_t sec = end_time->tv_sec - start_time->tv_sec;
    int64_t nsec;
    if (end_time->tv_nsec >= start_time->tv_nsec) {
        nsec = end_time->tv_nsec - start_time->tv_nsec;
    } else {
        nsec = 1000000000 - (start_time->tv_nsec - end_time->tv_nsec);
        sec -= 1;
    }
    return sec > 0 ? sec * 1000000000 : 0 + nsec > 0 ? nsec : 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct timespec start_time;
    struct timespec end_time;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start_time);
    puts("Hello!\n");
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end_time);
    printf("Oh, look! It took me %" PRId64 " nanoseconds to say hi!\n",
           get_elapsed_time(&start_time, &end_time));
}
```

Hope it helps.  Good Luck!